# Are there superset/subset relations between the sets of permissions of user owner, work group and other for a file?

Tags: linux, files, permissions

> Unix files have two kinds of ownership: user and group, each with its
>   own permissions.  Normally, the owner of a file should have full
>   access to it, whereas members of a work group to which the owner
>   belongs might have limited access, and everyone else, even less
>   access. This last category is called other in Unix documentation.

For a file,

- are the permissions for its work group necessarily permissions of its user owner?

  Since its user owner is a member of its work group, I guess the answer is yes, unless its work group excludes its user owner in the case of permissions. The permissions of its user owner may be more than those of its work group.
- are the permissions for its user owner necessarily permissions of other?

  Some said 'other'  means the entire world. In that sense its work group should be a subset of 'other', so I guess the answer is yes, unless 'other' excludes its work group. The permissions of its work group may be more than those of 'other'.

If it matters, I am focusing on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions under Unix-like systems use an octal representation.

It begins with an optional special permission, followed by `u`ser, `g`roup, `o`thers.  `u`, `g`, and `o` permissions are a combination of the following ORed together:

- `r`ead: 4
- `w`rite: 2
- e`x`ecute: 1

Therefore, the permission 0774 would allow its owner and group full access but read-only access to others.

Those permissions, including the special permission, are independent from one another.

Files also have a single owner and group, which are also independent, in their attributes.

It is therefore possible for the owner to have read-only access while members of groupX have read-write access, and people not matching either owner or group criteria having full access.

Lets consider user `john` that changes permissions of `text.txt` to `0467`, ownership to `john`, and group to `operator`:

```
$ chown john:operator text.txt
$ chmod 0467 text.txt
$ ls -l text.txt
-r--rw-rwx 1 john operator 0 Dec 29 00:57 text.txt
```

If `john` is not part of the `operator` group, he will not be able to update the file contents:

```
$ echo hi > text.txt
text.txt: Permission denied
```

But he can still change the permissions on the file, and update the file:

```
$ chmod u+w text.txt
$ echo hi > text.txt
$ ls -l text.txt
-rw-rw-rwx 1 john operator 3 Dec 29 00:57 text.txt
```

Note that accessing a file also involves folder permissions throughout the directory tree.

Comment: Thanks. For a file, Is its user owner  a member of its work group? Is its work group   a subset of 'other'? In your example, must 'john' be a member of the 'operator' group, and must the 'operator' group a subset of 'other'?

Comment: What I say is that they are **independent**.  In my example, `john` is not in the `operator` group and therefore can not update the file even if he is the owner.

Comment: Is 'other' defined as all except its user owner and its work group?

Comment: That is right.  As shown in my example, `john` would not have had a permission error if `others` included his account.

Comment: If 'john' is a member of the 'operator' group, must his permissions include the permissions of the group? Otherwise, it doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: Note that I added to my example to show that the owner can change his permissions without write access which is irrelevant to file attributes.

Comment: Suppose a program (`bash echo` in my example) tried to write to the file.  The system would start by checking if the user has write access.  If not, it would check if the user is part of the file's group and whether that grants him write access.  If not **and** user is **neither** the owner or in the file's group, it checks the `others` permission.  The process ends as soon as it gets a positive response.

Comment: My question was that when the user owner of a file is a member of its work group, whether it is a must to specify the permissions of its user owner so that they contain those of its work group, and whether it is neither possible nor meaningful to specify otherwise.

Comment: I just realized I made a small imprecision in my last comment.  If the user is the owner, only user permissions are checked.  If user is **not** the owner and is part of the file's group, only group permissions are checked.  And if the user is neither the owner or in the file's group, `others` permission are checked.

Comment: To continue with the same example, even if `john` is part of the `operator` group, he will not be able to write to the file if the user permission is not granted (0467).